# Auth Guard - How to lazily call two observables?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

In my auth guard, I want to first check the NGRX store by calling `this.store.select(userStatus)` which returns an `Observable<boolean>`, if the value is true, return true. If the value is false, I want to call `this.userService.authCheck()` which also returns an `Observable<boolean>` to finally determine what to return, how should I implement my `canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {}` method?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use an RXJS combination operator.  My 2 second guess is merge: https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/merge

Answer (score 0):

So you need to return an observable from canActivate that should emits a boolean value and you need to call one observable returning method first and check if it's returned true or if it's returned false then you need to call another method who will return true or false.

Your rxjs reciepe should look something like this :

```ts
function canActivate(
  route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot
): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.store.select(userStatus).pipe(
    switchMap(d => d ? of(true) : this.userService.authCheck())
  );
}
```

[Canactivate documentation can be found here](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)

Comment: You'll also need `take(1)` to complete the chain